# Insulating exterior roof/wall from inside

Tags: drywall, walls, insulation, roof

I am trying to figure out how to insulate my bedroom wall from the inside. The exterior-facing wall is on a sloping roof. This summer I had a Velux window installed and I was able to see the near total lack of insulation on this wall. Now it makes sense why it is always so cold! I haved zoned radiator heating and this room almost never warms to past 18º even with the radiator running, so I want to insulate this wall. Sound insulation is not an issue here, I am really looking to just keep the warmth inside.

I was thinking that I could put sheets of PIR insulation, maybe 6-7cm thick (Rd value 2,7-3,1) and then drywall over it. I just have some questions because I've heard this can be an issue with moisture. What if I use a plastic barrier between the existing drywall and the new insulation sheets (and eventual drywall)? And how do you frame around the window? I am no stranger to working with drywall but I am a bit confused how to do this around the window because it's slanted. Also, there will be no electricity on this wall. Could I really just put some PIR sheets between framing wood and then drywall over it?

Photos: https://imgur.com/a/cDTfJyr

Comment: By-the-book in the US is https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR806.5. With all of that air circulation between the top of your subroof and the roof tiles, it looks like the subroof can dry nicely to the exterior. I would be tempted to install the cheapest insulation available and drywall over it.